# Filter the products by selecting the checkbox

Tags: commerce

I am developing an e commerce website. I want to display the product catalog on the left sidebar as check-boxes. When the user will select the products, the page should get loaded with those products. I am new to drupal. I know that I will have to use Taxonomy. Please let me know what else i have to use to achieve this? And how all these are linked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking is filtering and not just displaying the products according to their taxonomy terms, then maybe you are looking for the [facet api](http://drupal.org/project/facetapi) module with [apachesolr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr)